# What is the essence of "exposing" an API especially in Google Cloud Endpoint?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, annotations, google-cloud-endpoints

I am totally new to the whole Google Cloud Endpoint/Google App Engine world. If you have gone through the Hello World example that Google provides(and you probably have), you might remember that there are 2 classes that are auto-generated for you: `MyBean` and `MyEndpoint`.

These are something like this:

```
/**
 * The object model for the data we are sending through endpoints
 */
public class MyBean {

    private String myData;

    public String getData() {
        return myData;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        myData = data;
    }
}
```

And,

```
/**
 * An endpoint class we are exposing
 */
@Api(
        name = "myApi",
        version = "v1",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "backend.myapplication.DJ.example.com",
                ownerName = "backend.myapplication.DJ.example.com",
                packagePath = ""
        )
)
public class MyEndpoint {

    /**
     * A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
    public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String name) {
        MyBean response = new MyBean();
        response.setData("Hi, " + name);

        return response;
    }

}
```

Now, I examined the code in index.html(which gets opened on deploying the backend). I found the following call in the javascript:

```
gapi.client.myApi.sayHi({'name': name}).execute(
```

Now, I can see that myApi is the name through annotation and sayHi() is the corresponding method, What I don't understand is the concept of exposing an API and annotation is aiding in that. There isn't any information about exposing APIs.

Could anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question can be divided in 3 parts:

1/ What is exposing an API?
Basically, you are offering an access to your business logic through an Interface (the API), with full control on what you want to show or not. This Stack Exchange answer is a great explanation: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203844/what-does-it-mean-to-expose-something

2/ What are these annotations in the auto-generated endpoints class?
If I can summarize it like that, Google endpoint is a "framework" which generates "default" APIs based on your java beans. By default you get CRUD operations in the API, but you can modify and/or enrich the endpoint to offer more complex business logic. The Endpoints classes that are generated include specific annotations that are used by the framework (in particular while generating a corresponding servlet) and define the URI you will call to interact with the methods of the APIs. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/

3/ What is this gapi.client call?
gapi stands for Google API Client Library. It is the library that is offered by Google to interact with Endpoints from a web browser. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/
You could use other methods to call the Endpoint APIs, like jquery Ajax methods (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), since Endpoints follow the REST architectural style. Note that you can call your endpoints from other "clients" than a web browser, e.g. an Android or iOS App. In these cases, you would not use the Google API Client Library but some other libraries.

I hope this clarifies a bit. Do not hesitate to ask for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response and reference links. As I have understood, the key to understanding this system is identifying the parties. So if I want to expose my libraries through an interface, it can be done through the provided annotations.(facilitated by Google). But in case if I am developing on Android, I would just want to call Google's APIs for handling requests to my App. My backend module would handle them and would have just the Servlets to handle them. Also, the backend module would be deployed on the server. In these interactions, I couldn't find the need for exposing my code. contd...

Comment: So, I am good to go without exposure right?  And the only scenario where I might need the exposure is when the server wants to send a request to my code(haven't thought of any such scenario yet).

Comment: I am not 100% sure to understand your needs. If your goal is to have your Android App interacting with your back-end, for e.g. store data in the Cloud Datastore, Cloud Endpoints is indeed the way to go. By using your words I would say that you should "call Google's APIs for handling requests FROM my App".  I would suggest you have a look at these very good tutorials about endpoints and Android: https://rominirani.com/gradle-tutorial-part-8-gradle-app-engine-endpoints-android-studio-6584358b29fd#.bkyd868z9.